# php convert array to multidimensional and add value to it

Tags: php, arrays

currently this is my one dimensional array looks like

```
 [0] => Spiderman 
 [1] => Burger 
 [3] => Batman 
 [4] => Robin
```

now i want to add another key at each array value, for example

```
 [0]['isMovie'] = 'Yes'
 [1]['isMovie'] = 'No'
 [2]['isMovie'] = 'Yes'
 [3]['isMovie'] = 'Yes'
```

so that next time when i iterate through the array, i will know which value is a movie or not.

i tried something like `[0]['isMovie'] = 'Yes'` but it seems it just changed the current value of the array to something like Ypiderman

Comment: you can't have your array values be both a string and an array at the same time.  You need an array of objects/structs/arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array structure *could* look like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Batman',
        'isMovie' => true,
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'phpisuber01 is awesome',
        'isMovie' => false,
    ),
);
```

You would access the values by doing something *like* this:

```
echo $var[0]['Name']; //returns Batman
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to create a name index.  You will have a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array('name'=> 'SpiderMan', 'isMovie'=> 'Yes');
$arr[] = array('name'=> 'Burger', 'isMovie'=> 'No');
$arr[] = array('name'=> 'Batman', 'isMovie'=> 'Yes');
$arr[] = array('name'=> 'Robin', 'isMovie'=> 'Yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[0] = array('0' => array[0], 'isMovie' => 'Yes');
$array[1] = array('1' => array[1], 'isMovie' => 'No');
```

... and so on